# UIBarButtonItem - How to make translucent black?

Tags: ios

Other than creating new button background images, is there a way to set UIBarButtonItems to have a translucent black look just like the UINavigationBar is capable of having?

I've tried setting tintColor to a UIColor of black with 0.7 for the alpha, but tintcolor appears to ignore the alpha setting entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that setting any `tintColor` disregards the alpha because the use of alpha is implied when you're *tinting* something. Your best bet is to create stretchable background images and use the new appearance API on `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: Thanks, I found this dev app that comes in quite handy for this purpose: http://blog.waynehartman.com/articles/how-to-create-a-pixel-perfect-uibarbuttonitem-of-any-color.aspx